# ESET does not provide protection and always wants a restart

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus

I get these warnings, although I have already restarted my PC twice.

Translation by me:

- Security warning
- Computer restart required
- Realtime file protection is not functional

[image: Screenshot]

I have ESET 14.0.21.0. My license is valid. Windows is 10 v1903, Build 18362.1082.

I can't update Windows, because of VMWare Workstation. And I can't update VMWare Workstation, because the newer versions no longer support the Xeon processor I have.

How could I get rid of this reboot loop?

Comment: You will have to provide an English translation for the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked:

- uninstall ESET 14.0.21.0
- reboot
- install ESET 14.0.22.0 [from scratch](https://www.eset.com/us/home/antivirus/download/).

Answer (score 1):

> ESET NOD32 Antivirus has been updated to a newer version. A restart of
> the computer is required to take over the change and guarantee optimal
> protection.
>
> Restart your computer
>
> this feature could be detected and 1hr computer is not protected from
> certain threats

**(1)** The most recent version of ESET I see is 13.2.16 . How did you get 14.0.21.0 ? Is it an early version, or just the very latest version? Try updating or reinstalling ESET again.

**(2)** Windows 10 V1903 is now getting quite old. Perhaps you might consider updating it and see if that will help. New ESET may work better in new Windows.

Upgrading to V2004 from V1903 will re-write and repair the operating system.

If you wish to make initial repairs to V1903, you can try the following:

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator

dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup

dism.exe /online  /cleanup-image /restorehealth

SFC  /SCANNOW

Restart when the above is complete and test again.

Comment: How did I get this version? I always upgraded ESET when I was asked to. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kblMf.png

Comment: It says there is 14.0.22.0 available, but for whatever reason, it will not update to that version. The executable seems digitally signed and timestamped by ESET + Digicert

Comment: You should either repair V1903 or (preferably) upgrade to V2004.  The newest version of ESET may want newer Windows.